# Clip sound from running sound clip

Tags: blackberry, java-me

Does anybody know how to cut a sound clip from running sound file? I am working on one blackberry application, Is anybody have any sample code or link please give me that.

Thanks

Regards
V Singh

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to cut a part of sound file. You have to study sound file formats and deal with sound file binary structure.

No, I don't have sample code, but you can write it by yourself, after studying sound file formats.

Comment: Hi Rafael, Thanks for your reply, But I have a query, how can we cut a clip from running sound file on the time bases, Suppose I have a 60 sec sound clip and I want a clip from 20sec to 35sec from  existing clip.

Comment: As I said before you need to know format of the sound (mp3, ogg, etc) file. When you know the format you can parse file header, extract the sound stream and cut the necessary binary part of the sound file and compose a new sound file with new header and new (shorter) sound stream.

Comment: To find information on sound file formats use Google. There is a lot of information about the subject.

Answer (score 1):

//Sample code to cut a sound file(AMR)

long startTime = player.getMediaTime();
long endTime = player.getMediaTime();

```
    private void cutByTimeDuration(long startTime, long endTime) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    byte[] byte1 = readDSoundFile("hello.amr"); //custom method original file 
    int noFramesStart = (int) (startTime / 20000);
    long noBytesStart = (noFramesStart * 32) + 6;
    int noFramesEnd = (int) (endTime / 20000);
    long noBytesEnd = (noFramesEnd * 32) + 6;
    byte[] byte2 = new byte[(int) (noBytesEnd - noBytesStart + 6)];
    System.arraycopy(byte1, 0, byte2, 0, 6);
    System.arraycopy(byte1, (int) noBytesStart, byte2, 6,
            (int) (noBytesEnd - noBytesStart));

    try {

        FileConnection file = (FileConnection) Connector.open(filePath
                + "/" + "xyz.amr", Connector.READ_WRITE);
        if (file.exists())
            file.delete();

        // if (!file.exists() )
        {
            file.create();
            OutputStream out = file.openOutputStream();
            int length = byte2.length;// -1;
            out.write(byte2, 0, length);
            Thread.yield();

            out.flush();
            out.close();
            file.close();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

}
```